# How to scale activity to fit the no of images exactly without any space

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I'm facing a very strange problem. Here I have total 8 images in Gridview Style where each image is exactly 392×500 Size. But when I run app, There is alwayas a small space left  below the last 8th image.

Here is my code

```html
public class BooksPage extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {


    int images[] = {R.drawable.phy,R.drawable.chem,R.drawable.drawable_logy,R.drawable.drawable_geology,R.drawable.bbs,R.drawable.drawable_chartered,R.drawable.bachelor,R.drawable.bachelor};

    String stream[]= {"MSC Physics","MSC Chemistry","MSC Biology",
            "MSC Geology","BBS|BBA","CA","Bachelor","+2 Science"};
    TextView navName,navEmail;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_books_page);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("पुस्तक किनबेच");

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        View navHeaderView = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
        navName = (TextView)navHeaderView.findViewById(R.id.nav_name);
        navEmail = (TextView)navHeaderView.findViewById(R.id.nav_mail);

        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        RecyclerView favPlaces = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.favPlaces);
        StaggeredGridLayoutManager layoutManager = new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(2,StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        layoutManager.setGapStrategy(StaggeredGridLayoutManager.GAP_HANDLING_NONE);
        favPlaces.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        favPlaces.setHasFixedSize(true);
        ArrayList<BookDetails> placeList = getPlaces();

        if (!isNetworkStatusAvialable(this)) {


            Toast.makeText(this, "No Internet!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();



        }

        StaggeredAdapter staggeredAdapter = new StaggeredAdapter(this,placeList);
        favPlaces.setAdapter(staggeredAdapter);
        navName.setText(PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).getString("name","null"));
        navEmail.setText(PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).getString("email","null"));
    }
    private ArrayList<BookDetails> getPlaces() {
        ArrayList<BookDetails> details = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int index=0; index<images.length;index++){
            details.add(new BookDetails(images[index],stream[index]));
        }
        return details;
    }

   

}
```

My xml code of adapter is

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
        app:cardCornerRadius="4dp">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/placePic"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:scaleType="fitXY" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/placeName"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
                android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textSize="16sp"/>


        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Then I though maybeincrease in size of images will do the trick but whether I make the image size 50×50 or 1000×1000, The image is always same size and space is also constant.

Here is the screenshot
[image]

and again same with another image
[![enter image description here][2]][2]

But funny  part is  when I use the same image of 7th poition in 8th position also.....Then space disappers and images fit exactly.

Here is the screenshot
[image]

what is the problem here? How can I fix it any help is appreciated

I'm using photoshop to change width and height of  my Images by Saving for 
Web.

Comment: Just only one picture is ok here, Also you may need to provide your inflated xml code + activity code to check the problem

Comment: Oho my bad, Ok I have edited my question. Please check.

Comment: Your xml isn't bad. now  remove one picture and add your activity code

Comment: Ok done..that. Please have a look.

Comment: even in "correct" fig, I noticed the right item is a little higher than left item.

Comment: yes indeed there is one image at 4th position and  is also the same size that is 392 by 500. but still it has gone outward by slight position upward. But  all the images are same size....and I thought it can be considered..sine there is only a small gap..but last image has a lot of gap which is noticable.

Comment: Now use my provided answer in your code. Let me know what the output is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below code will solve the problem. But may require little edit.

Add the below code inside your `fragment`/`Activity` `onCreate`/ `ocreateView`. Here you only need item decorator for your recycler to scale the item

```
 mRecycler.addItemDecoration(new GridSpacingItemDecoration(2, dpToPx(2), true));
```

Add  create a method `dpToPx`

```
 /**
     * Converting dp to pixel
     */
    private int dpToPx(int dp) {
        Resources r = getResources();
        return Math.round(TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, dp, r.getDisplayMetrics()));
    }
```

Now create a class for `GridSpacingItemDecoration` inside your activity/fragment

```
 /**
     * RecyclerView item decoration - give equal margin around grid item
     */
    public class GridSpacingItemDecoration extends RecyclerView.ItemDecoration {

        private int spanCount;
        private int spacing;
        private boolean includeEdge;

        GridSpacingItemDecoration(int spanCount, int spacing, boolean includeEdge) {
            this.spanCount = spanCount;
            this.spacing = spacing;
            this.includeEdge = includeEdge;
        }

        @Override
        public void getItemOffsets(Rect outRect, View view, RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state) {
            int position = parent.getChildAdapterPosition(view); // item position
            int column = position % spanCount; // item column

            if (includeEdge) {
                outRect.left = spacing - column * spacing / spanCount; // spacing - column * ((1f / spanCount) * spacing)
                outRect.right = (column + 1) * spacing / spanCount; // (column + 1) * ((1f / spanCount) * spacing)

                if (position < spanCount) { // top edge
                    outRect.top = spacing;
                }
                outRect.bottom = spacing; // item bottom
            } else {
                outRect.left = column * spacing / spanCount; // column * ((1f / spanCount) * spacing)
                outRect.right = spacing - (column + 1) * spacing / spanCount; // spacing - (column + 1) * ((1f /    spanCount) * spacing)
                if (position >= spanCount) {
                    outRect.top = spacing; // item top
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: It throws me error of cannot resolve  mRecycler..what should I do here?

Comment: Ok solved the problem but stil small gap is visible..but it  can be considered.